# Running docker on python subprocess not working

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a docker (inside Windows Subsystem for Linux, WSL) using a Python script. From the command line, this would be done with the following commands:

```
wsl docker start dock1
```

```
wsl docker attach dock1
```

I tried to run these commands using python subprocess. The first command worked, but the second ('docker attach') did not.

The python code I used for these commands are as follows:

```
subprocess.run(["wsl", "docker", "start", "dock1"])
subprocess.run(["wsl", "docker", "attach", "dock1"])
```

The second command gives the error:

```
'the input device is not a TTY'
```

I've also tried using the '-t' and '-it' flags on the attach command, but these are not recognised.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you just want to see the std output from a docker container (use `docker logs`)? Do you want to run some commands programmatically inside the docker container (use `docker exec`)? Or do you want to be able to open a shell within the docker container and manually enter some commands (now you want `docker attach`)?

Comment: As part of my work, I need to make a python script which transfers logs (generated by running tests) to hardware device, which runs on remote server. My PC has a Windows operating system but the tests are run on a Linux system embedded into the Windows OS, hence I need to get my Python script to access docker container in order to get the source file. So to answer your question, docker logs won't help me here, I thought 'docker attach' would be the correct command but from your response, I'm guessing 'docker exec' would be more useful for this?

Comment: You want `docker cp` then. eg. `docker cp <container-name>:/path/to/log/file /wsl/dest/path`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 0):

Your issues occurs when trying to attach an interactive terminal session to a process that isn't connected to a terminal.
This is a common issue when running `subprocess.run` in Python as it does not by default allocate a pseudo-TTY.

You can try following:

```
import os

os.system("wsl docker start dock1")
os.system("wsl docker attach dock1")
```

The `os.system` function runs the command in a subshell, which is typically connected to a TTY.

Comment: I ran this and it gave me the same error unfortunately